# Ubuntu boot failed after trying to repair boot

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, bios, boot-repair

In my new SSD harddrive I changed BIOS into UEFI and partition table form mbt to gpt. I installed Windows , updated it , installed Linux . I used Linux whole day. At the end of the day I used Widnows a little bit. Now I cannot boot Linux. I used boot-repair, firstly something poped out that I have to turn off the boot security or smth like that ,so I did it in BIOS, then i used boot-repair again (http://paste.ubuntu.com/12679443/) and it should have worked , but it didn't. Now if I turn of my laptop it says "Ubuntu boot failed" .

Comment: Have you tried doing a complete shutdown in Windows - not the quick start stuff, a full shut down?

Comment: Can u tell me how I can do it ?

Comment: I created a shortcut "shutdown /s /t 0" and used it. But like earlier "ubuntu boot failed" .

Comment: The error message you're seeing is one with which I'm not familiar. Could you take a screen shot (digital photo) and post a link to it? The context may provide clues. Beyond that, if Secure Boot is disabled, a USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) might at least enable you to boot Ubuntu temporarily.

Comment: I don't really do much with Windows these days so that's why my question was mostly for clarification and troubleshooting @jakubby. Is your BIOS set to boot to the proper bootloader which is on the Windows partition (sda3) according to your pastebin? Other than that, I'm unfamiliar with this error thus it was a question and not an answer. Hopefully it narrows this down for someone else and they can jump in and help while saving some you both some time.

Comment: There is the links:
http://www.tinypic.pl/lr7644dgy3qw
http://www.tinypic.pl/gblu36ry781g
http://www.tinypic.pl/1zqqpki98iu9
http://www.tinypic.pl/18n4qq80w96y
http://www.tinypic.pl/1zfvei7kkl6n
http://www.tinypic.pl/3g65kijx8pwv

Comment: I dont remember if i created more partition than one (ext4 for linux)  and I read that I need extra small partition for boot (in gpt) . Is it possible that this is issue ? Sadly GParted dont find my partition (I'm not sure but I think that Gparted doesnt support GPT ... :( ).

Comment: If it's going to be helpful I will send you a screenshot from console with all partition. I read somewhere that I had to do a GRUB2's partition by mysleft and I didnt do it. However it worked fine until I randomly chose to use Windows for a while .If u guys dont have any solutions I can try to reinstall Ubuntu (but gparted doesnt see any partitions in live session).
After installing windows though uefi , he created 3 partion , one of them is windows boot manager.I found something (https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GRUB2#UEFI_with_GPT) should I make this extra partition ?

Comment: So after using  rEFInd boot manager i succeded and used linux ,but after rerun i dont have any grub2 menu and no linux in boot menu (only windows boot manager) . I think I have to create a special parttition for boot linux ,but I dont know how  or just use boot-repair in some special way , but again I dont know exaclty how should i do it :/ . Help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your windows by hold SHIFT key to enter UEFI screen (maybe differ with others laptop/computer), then see if there are another ubuntu option in your uefi (because it was happen to me), choose the right option that can makes you logon to ubuntu, then try to reorder uefi boot menu. Otherwise, you can do it by easyuefi from windows. hope that will solve your problem.